# Bug in counter for error page redirect on 4 invalid attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have code which keeps track of the number of times a button has been clicked. When the page first loads, a counter is set to 0. On every postback, the counter is incremented by 1. I have only one button on the page.

If the user enters invalid details for 4 times, he is redirected to an error page. Otherwise, he is redirected to a confirmation page.

This is my code:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    Session["Count"] = 0;
}

else
{
    if (Session["Count"] == null)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("CheckOutErrorPage.htm");
    }

    else
    {
        int count = (int)Session["Count"];

        if (count == 3)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("CheckOutFailure.aspx");
        }

        else
        {
            count++;
            Session["Count"] = count;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works as it should except that if the user enter invalid details for 3 times and then he enters VALID details on the 4th time, the user is redirected to the Error Page (because he has tried 4 times) instead of the confirmation page.

How can I solve this please?

Comment: Why not just change `count == 3` to `count == 4`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem, but this sounds like terrible usability, why care if someone enters something incorrectly (as long as they're not being malicious)?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally running that code even if the entry is correct?

Comment: @Chris It's like Loren said.  The validation of the details occurs after the option 4 check.

Comment: @Matthew That's the point.  The page shows a CAPTCHA image and only allows the user to input for four times.  Otherwise, the session is invalidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing in your code that goes to the success option.

I'm going to guess that it's after this code, this code executes before it checks if it's valid and thus you take the error path on try #4 no matter what.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry but I have been working all day and I am making silly mistakes.  Thanks :)